# Broad and opinion-based question closed without an answer despite many similar questions getting answers

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I asked [a obviously broad, opinion-based, etc., [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45384829/8177388).  Now, my only concern is, it has been closed before being answered!  There are *a lot* of questions on SO that are "obviously broad, opinion-based" (like, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038976/c-reference-book), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048000/books-to-refer-for-learning-oop-through-c), etc.).  They have been *answered before being closed*.  Why is it so?  I do not mind the question being closed, but I seek an answer first, the reason being I won't get an answer *from the experts* anywhere else!

Comment: "I do not mind the question being closed, but I seek an answer first" - the point of closing a question is to *prevent* answers being added (from the point in time where the question is closed), because it's deemed to be not in a fit state to receive answers. Sure, if someone has added an answer before the question is closed, that answer remains - but that's a different matter.

Comment: "the only reason being I won't get an answer anywhere else!" - if a question isn't appropriate anywhere else, that *doesn't* make it appropriate to have it on Stack Overflow. SO shouldn't be a dumping ground for inappropriate questions.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I meant answer _from experts._  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I don't see how "from experts" makes any difference to my comments. Desiring an answer from experts doesn't automatically make a question on-topic on SO.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I don't think I _ever_ said my question was on-topic.  My only concern is - it was closed _before_ it was answered, unlike what has been done with other questions.

Comment: Again, the point of closing is to *stop* answers being added, because the question shouldn't be there at all. (Duplicates are a slight variation on this; having dupes can be a good thing, whereas I'd hope most other closed questions would be deleted over time, never having been answered.) It sounds like you think it's fine for SO to be a dumping ground for all questions - answer them *then* close them, which means there's no incentive not to ask the bad question in the first place. I disagree strongly: if you want answers, ask appropriate questions.

Comment: Yes, sometimes a later-closed question will be answered first, but that's the exception, *not* the rule or the intended sequence of events.

Comment: @JonSkeet, nevermind.  :)  I expected this, TBH.  Was just trying to be lucky and come into that _exception_.  All the best and have a good one.

Comment: "I do not mind the question being closed, but I seek an answer first" - That's a problem. You don't care about the community of this site, knowing that it would waste most people's time if you post it. However, you still expect the community being nice with you and provide useful answers to your innapropriate question. Why can't it work that way? Because of justice.

Comment: On a different note, try following @JonSkeet advices and enjoy StackOverflow for what it's meant to be. Community here is good to be part of, just try it and you might enjoy it. Be nice with people who take their time to help others and they will provide you awesome answers.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A veteran member of Stack Overflow once described getting away with one of these questions as akin to winning the lottery.

Yes, you can find examples of lottery winners. You might even win yourself. But if you spend all your money on playing the lotto and *don't* win, that's no big surprise, and you really should know better than to try.

Comment: Yep, this is the answer that I was looking for.  :)  I lost the lottery this time.

Comment: You might point out that Stack Overflow offers 100% refunds to askers who are unsatisfied with the answers they receive.

Answer (score 17):

> Now, my only concern is, it has been closed before being answered!

Off-topic questions are supposed to be closed before answering. It doesn't always happen, but it is the ideal.

> There are a lot many questions on SO that are "obviously broad, opinion-based" (like, this, this, this, etc.).

Yeah, back in 2010 and before, rules were rather different, and such questions could be on-topic (although one was closed as a duplicate). 7+ year old questions aren't a good indicators of current rules.

> I do not mind the question being closed, but I seek an answer first, the only reason being I won't get an answer anywhere else!

You shouldn't expect off-topic questions to be answered, there's no guarantee even on-topic questions will be answered.

Answer (score 12):

Two fatal mistakes here:

- Stack Overflow is ***not*** the best platform to ask broad, subjective, and opinionated questions.  Asking how to sharpen your skillset, while indeed an important discussion, doesn't belong here.

  You can try your hand at chat, but your mileage may vary.
- You are looking at **old and antiquated questions** as examples, and these are ***not*** indicative of what we allow today.  We *don't* allow any of those questions today.

Answer (score 7):

> I do not mind the question being closed, but I seek an answer first

... is similar to saying:

> I do not mind you putting out this dangerous fire I carelessly started on your property without your permission, but I want to finish cooking this steak before you put it out.

That is to say: you're mostly missing the point.

Stack Overflow is a big place, there may be fires elsewhere we haven't gotten to yet, and maybe some dry leaves that's been left in the sun for a while will light on fire at some point (i.e. old on topic questions can become off topic as rules change).

---

There are most definitely other places where experts hang out that have different rules than Stack Overflow.